# preventing setup.py from downloading beta versions

Tags: python, setuptools

We have a `setup.py` file which has a list of dependencies to install when doing `python setup.py install` or `python setup.py develop`.

`pip` is able to distinguish between pre-released versions and released versions.

`pip` will download `1.0.10b2` only if provided with `--pre`, otherwise it will download `1.0.9` which is the latest stable version (for example).

The `setuptools` however seems to download the latest pre-released version `1.0.10b2`.

How do you prevent it from downloading beta packages?

Comment: `setuptools` uses `easy_install` under the hood, and `easy_install` does not distinct between prerelease and release versions. Some day, when `setuptools` drops `easy_install` usage and switched to `pip`, this problem will disappear, but for now the only resort is to explicitly restrict the package version: `install_requires=['mypkg<1.0.10']` etc.

Comment: @hoefling thanks that's sad

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54796975/how-to-exclude-or-ignore-package-pre-releases-with-setuptools; though that question was posted later, it has 20x views and a few more votes.