# How to exclude or ignore package pre-releases with setuptools?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, setuptools, distutils

I was using setuptools with a `tensorflow` package dependency. I noticed when I run `setup.py install`, it finds `tensorflow 1.13.0rc2`. When I run with `pip`, it finds `tensorflow 1.12`.

Then I found [this ticket](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/855) which seems to indicate that `setuptools` includes package pre-releases (i.e. release candidates, RCs), whereas `pip` does not unless you specify the `--pre` argument.

**I was wondering if anyone had any tips on how to exclude pre-releases from `setuptools` so that `python setup.py install` won't pull them in.**

Comment: You could try adding the dependency with `"tensorflow ~= 1.12"`.  That wouldn't pick up 1.13 automatically when it's available, but it would keep you from getting 1.13, I believe.

Comment: BTW, the relevant PEPs are [PEP-440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/) and [PEP-508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Yeah I was hoping for an option that allows future releases, but not RCs. However it looks like including RCs is totally PEP compliant based on your links so perhaps keeping RCs around isn't that terrible.

Comment: Actually, it's totally NOT PEP compliant! https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#handling-of-pre-releases
I've commented about this in the ticket you linked to.  But it doesn't look like it's likely to change any time soon, given that there's been no activity on that ticket in 3 years. (I guess technically, it is "compliant" since the PEP says SHOULD rather than MUST, but it's not... PEP ideal) :D